# jQuery getJSON returns null when querying Google maps even when results are valid

Tags: jquery, json

I cannot seem to make this simple code work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.getJSON('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cebu&sensor=false&region=ph', 
    function(results) {
        alert(results);
    });
});
</script>
```

It always alerts null even though the results for the json is something like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "locality", "political" ],
    "formatted_address": "Cebu City, Philippines",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Cebu City",
      "short_name": "Cebu City",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Cebu",
      "short_name": "Cebu",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Central Visayas",
      "short_name": "Central Visayas",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Philippines",
      "short_name": "PH",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 10.3455617,
        "lng": 123.8969328
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 10.3016523,
          "lng": 123.8329031
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 10.3894650,
          "lng": 123.9609625
        }
      },
      "bounds": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 10.2594350,
          "lng": 123.8668156
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 10.3991826,
          "lng": 123.9401150
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

What else do I need to do? I have read back-and-forth the jquery manual but I cannot seem to make the simple example work.

Thanks!

Comment: `json-p` is the `key` (that was poetic!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson
paragraph 3 :
"Note that the site you're trying to call needs to support JSON-P output."

Are you sure maps.google.com supports this?

Comment: Yes, it does not support JSON-P. Also found this in Stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api