# How to call google map geocode service with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, geocode

I'm trying to get the LatLng from google map geocode api. my code is below with address values is "New York, NY"

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data: {
        sensor: false,
        address: address
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

But I'm not getting any values in alert.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you getting? Please use Firebug (or equivalent) for debugging. What does te request contain?

Comment: @Fokko Driesprong checked in firebug, getting data as empty and url as http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=NewYork%2C+NY  and when pasting this url in browser address bar giving the results. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to contact the API regarding the [rules](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html).

```
$.getJSON( {
    url  : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data : {
        sensor  : false,
        address : address
    },
    success : function( data, textStatus ) {
        console.log( textStatus, data );
    }
} );
```

**Edit:**

How dumb of me, shouldn't be on stackoverflow in the morning! The problem is a cross-domain request. For security reasons this is not allowed. See: [How to make cross-domain AJAX calls to Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api)

Please use Google's own [Geocoding client](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding).

Comment: thanks again. I tried with the above code but no luck. By the way, before function i added "success:"

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error for address parameter in data. Can somebody help me how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 10):

there is no need to make use of jquery, Google maps javascript API v3 has build in its own functions which makes the API easy to use.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just as a side note, if you will be performing look-ups for international addresses, it's a good idea to use the componentRestrictions parameter rather than the address. 

`geocoder.geocode({
                    componentRestrictions: {
                        country: country,
                        postalCode: zip
                    }
                }, function (results, status) {
                
                }
});` This ensures that the API doesn't mis-interpret the values you are passing in as something it isn't (country as a city, etc)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is seeking help on this topic, this is how I have done it.  Note this is a reverse lookup, but a forward lookup should work the same way:

`

```
    function getLocation() {
var latdegrees=40.2298;
var londegrees=-41.88754;
     var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latdegrees + "," + londegrees + "YOUR API KEY";
    $.getJSON(url,function (data, textStatus) {
           var streetaddress=data.results[0].formatted_address;
          return streetaddress;
      });
     }`
```

Comment: Even though reverse geocoding wasn't asked for. Thanks for adding that anyway!

Answer (score 1):

V3 geocoding webservice doesn't support JSONP requests, but it's still available in V2

See: http://blog.futtta.be/2010/04/09/no-more-jsonp-for-google-geocoding-webservice/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Geocoder seems like is creating it's own callback.

```
geo.geocode({ 'address': myaddress }, function(data, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
        var myylocation = data[0].geometry.location;
        lat = myylocation.lat();
        lng = myylocation.lng();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or specify dataType to jsonp?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data: {
        sensor: false,
        address: address
    },
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```