# Trying to use Google Places API with JQuery's getJSON function

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, google-places-api

This is probably very basic but I'm trying to test the Google Places API. I'm going through the documentation and using some of the examples they provide. I'm trying to use the JQuery getJSON function because I've been able to successfully use it to access external JSON files asynchronously with it, so I thought it might be a good approach to getting the JSON results of the Google Places query. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<body>
<div id="message"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var requestURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key='my_google_places_key';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(requestURL, function (data) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                myAddress[i] = data.results[i].formatted_address;
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += myAddress[i] + "<br>";
                console.log(myAddress[i]);
            }

        });
    });  


</script>

</body>
```

According to the documentation the resulting JSON response to the query should be as follows:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
   ],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8750460,
               "lng" : 151.2052720
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "827f1ac561d72ec25897df088199315f7cbbc8ed",
         "name" : "Tetsuya's",
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAmmm3dlSVT3E7rIvwQ0lHBA4sayvxWEc4nZaXSSjRtfKRGoYnfr3d5AvQGk4e0u3oOErXsIJwtd3Wck1Onyw6pCzr8swW4E7dZ6wP4dV6AsXPvodwdVyqHgyGE_K8DqSp5McW_nFcci_-1jXb5Phv-RIQTzv5BjIGS0ufgTslfC6dqBoU7tw8NKUDHg28bPJlL0vGVWVgbTg",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Upper Level, Overseas Passenger Terminal/5 Hickson Road, The Rocks NSW, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8583790,
               "lng" : 151.2100270
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "f181b872b9bc680c8966df3e5770ae9839115440",
         "name" : "Quay",
         "rating" : 4.10,
         "reference" : "CnRiAAAADmPDOkn3znv_fX78Ma6X5_t7caEGNdSWnpwMIdDNZkLpVKPnQJXP1ghlySO-ixqs28UtDmJaOlCHn18pxpj7UQjRzR4Kmye6Gijoqoox9bpkaCAJatbJGZEIIUwRbTNIE_L2jGo5BDqiosqU2F5QdBIQbXKrvfQuo6rmu8285j7bDBoUrGrN4r6XQ-PVm260PFt5kwc3EfY",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "formatted_address" : "107 George Street, The Rocks NSW, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8597750,
               "lng" : 151.2085920
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "7beacea28938ae42bcac04faf79a607bf84409e6",
         "name" : "Rockpool",
         "rating" : 4.0,
         "reference" : "CnRlAAAAVK4Ek78r9yHV56I-zbaTxo9YiroCbTlel-ZRj2i6yGAkLwNMm_flMhCl3j8ZHN-jJyG1TvKqBBnKQS2z4Tceu-1kZupZ1HSo5JWRBKd7qt2vKgT8VauiEBQL-zJiKVzSy5rFfilKDLSiLusmdi88ThIQqqj6hKHn5awdj6C4f59ifRoUg67KlbpuGuuW7S1tAH_EyBl6KE4",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "formatted_address" : "483 George Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
         "events" : [
            {
              "event_id" : "7lH_gK1GphU",
              "summary" : "Google Maps Developer Meetup: Rockin' out with the Places API",
              "url" : "https://developers.google.com/places"
            }
          ],
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8731950,
               "lng" : 151.2063380
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png",
         "id" : "017049cb4e82412aaf0efbde890e82b7f2987c16",
         "name" : "Chinatown Sydney",
         "rating" : 4.0,
         "reference" : "CnRuAAAAsLNeRQtKD7TEUXWG6gYD7ByOVKjQE61GSyeGZrX-pOPVps2BaLBlH0zBHlrVU9DKhsuXra075loWmZUCbczKDPdCaP9FVJXB2NsZ1q7188pqRFik58S9Z1lcWjyVoVqvdUUt9bDMLqxVT4ENmolbgBIQ9Wy0sgDy0BgWyg5kfPMHCxoUOvmhfKC-lTefXGgnsRqEQwn8M0I",
         "types" : [
            "city_hall",
            "park",
            "restaurant",
            "doctor",
            "train_station",
            "local_government_office",
            "food",
            "health",
            "establishment"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If I copy this JSON script and save it to a file, I can access it and it displays the following result on the browser:

529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia
Upper Level, Overseas Passenger Terminal/5 Hickson Road, The Rocks NSW, Australia
107 George Street, The Rocks NSW, Australia
483 George Street, Sydney NSW, Australia

Which means it works. Is the getJSON function not parsing the JSON script properly?

Comment: See this answer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564830/parsing-google-geo-api-reverse-geocoding-with-jquery/39276042#answer-39276042

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

You can find demo's and documentation of how to use it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Comment: That may work, but I'm very curious as to why this code won't work with remote JSON scripts. As far as I could see, Google doesn't really show any worthy examples of how to consume their Google Places service using AJAX. How do people normally do it? Thanks for the response by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I more or less figured it out. I figured out what you need to do so that the getJSON function returns the JSON parsed data. You have to add "callback=?" to the query string.

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key="myKey"&callback=?';
```

However, now the problem is that I now get an error in my console saying that:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]   

"html_attributions" : [

 json?l...0080533 (line 2, col 3)
```

Which is weird because I checked the response in JSONLint and the format is valid. Also, the same response works if it's read from a local file.

Comment: 'callback' is needed to turn a JSON output into a JSONP output. Only JSONP can be used in JQM.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code

```
      <body>
     <div id="message"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/searc/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key='my_google_places_key';',
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
             for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            myAddress[i] = data.results[i].formatted_address;
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += myAddress[i] + "<br>";
            console.log(myAddress[i]);
        };
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
});  
 </script>
 </body>
```

you need to make it as Json callback since it is Cross Domain call