# jquery jsonp request to google maps is not returning results

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, jsonp, getjson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Google Geo API (Reverse Geocoding) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564830/parsing-google-geo-api-reverse-geocoding-with-jquery)

```
  $(window).load(function() {

var purl =  "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.759294499999996,-97.32799089999999&sensor=false";
  $.getJSON(purl,function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("#data").append(field + " ");
    });
  });

});
```

if you visit the url you will see results in json format. when I send this as a $.getJSON request its not returning anything under response on firebug its blank.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: getJSON will not work for cross domain requests. 

Example usage: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: well I have a longitude and latitude and I want to get city and state using that ... the example you showed me displays a map. I dont need that. any thoughts?

Comment: I'd look at the docs or the source code.  Specifically the codeAddress  method in that example.  I'll add the exact example google provides as an example.

Comment: Are you sure that the api you are requesting from returns JSONP? All i see is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

See the reverse geocoding example here:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Here is their example (minus the map):

```
  var geocoder;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
           alert(results[1].formatted_address);
        } else {
          alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

$().ready(function () {
    initialize();
    codeLatLng(32.759294499999996,-97.32799089999999);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : URL,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp : "jsoncallback",
        jsonpCallback : MSS,
        cache : true,
        success : function(service_data) {
            binding(service_data);

        },
        error : function(msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am not sure of the above answer