# latitude and longitude not saved google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from an address with google maps api and I don't get it how. The map is working by getting the address but there is a way for that address to take the lat and lon? The following code is working:

```
 <ng-map default-style="false" zoom="16" center="{{ '{{ getAddress() }}' }}" style="width: 100%; height: 430px;">
                <marker centered="true" position="{{ '{{ getMarkerPosition() }}' }}" draggable="true" on-dragend="onMarkerDragEnd($event)"></marker>
                <shape ng-if="showRegions" ng-repeat="shape in regions"
                        (...)
                </shape>
 </ng-map>
```

And the js:

```
 $scope.getMarkerPosition = function () {
            if (!$scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude || !$scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude) {
                return $scope.getObjectiveAddress();
            }

            return [$scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude, $scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude]
        };
```

The problem is that mapPinLocationLatitude and long are always null, in database are not salved and don't know why..

```
   $scope.getAddress = function () {
            var address = "..."; (here just concatenate the string with the address values(street, number, etc and it returned)

            return streetString + ', ' + address;
        };


     $scope.onMarkerDragEnd = function ($event) {
            $scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude = $event.latLng.lat();
            $scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude = $event.latLng.lng();
            $scope.updateRegions();
        };
```

So, my question is, any idea how to get the latitude and long and for example if I write: the map to be displayed correctly?

```
 <marker centered="true" position="{{ '{{ [address.mapPinLocationLatitude, address.mapPinLocationLongitude]}}' }}" draggable="true" on-dragend="onMarkerDragEnd($event)"></marker>
```

Comment: You want to get lat\lng from address with google maps?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Use [geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en)

[Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=en)

```
$.getJSON( {
url  : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
data : {
    sensor  : false,
    address : address
},
success : function( data, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus, data );
}
```

} );

Similar question on stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191325/how-to-call-google-map-geocode-service-with-jquery-ajax)