# json google maps geocode no response

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I am getting no response from the $.getJSON

```
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address +'&sensor=false',function(data){
        var resultsArray = data;
    });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much detail, but your problem is almost certainly your browser denying the cross-domain request (throwing an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error).

Instead, use Google's Geocoding API.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api) for more details.

Comment: Totally missed that. Yea, if the maps api supports JSONP, that'd also do the trick.