# Debugging jquery or javascript using firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I wrote a code in jquery. I was not running initially, then i checked online [jslint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) for syntax errors. I caught some errors. Now still the code was not working as expected. So i went for firebug. I haven't done a lot of debugging. I am new to it. Here is my code

```
var j = 2;
var friends = [];
var distance =[];


$(document).ready(function () {

      $('#button').click(function () {
        if (j < 11) {
            $('#friends').append('Friend' + j + ':<input type="text" id="friend' + j + '"/><br/><br/>');
            j++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Limit reached");
        }
    });



   $('button').click(function(){
  console.log("button clicked");
   var a =[];
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
     {
        a[i] = $("#friend" + i).val();
      }     


    var gurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"+
        "origins=" +
        a.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
        "&destinations=" +
        a.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
        "&sensor=false";


  jQuery.ajax(
          {
             type: "GET",
             url: gurl,
             dataType: 'jsonp'
          }).done(function (response) 
             {
                var rows = response.rows;
                  alert("hello there");

                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
                 {

                  for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
                {
                    distance[i][j] = rows[i].elements[j].distance;
                 }

                 }
          alert(distance[1][3]);
              });

        });
  });
```

Now, what it should do is Go to this [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%7Cchandigarh%20sector%2020%7Cchandigarh%20sector%2018%7Cpanchkula%20sector%2021%7C%7C&destinations=%7Cchandigarh%20sector%2020%7Cchandigarh%20sector%2018%7Cpanchkula%20sector%2021%7C%7C&sensor=false) and get the data from json file and store it inside the 2 dimensional array distance[][]. Finally after storing all the data, it should display the result of "distance[1][2]" as an alert.

Now i dont know whats wrong in this code and how to find the logical errors using firebug. What should make my work easy ?

ps: heres the HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <head>

    <title>TakeMeHome</title>

    <script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>


 </head>

  <body>
    <center>
        <form id="locations">
        Your Place:<input id="source" type="text"><br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="friends">
         Friend1:<input id="friend1" type="text"><br/>
        <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="button">
            Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <button>GO!</button>

        <br/><br/>
        <div id="map" style = "width: 500px; height: 500px"><br/>

        </form>
    </center>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add it to a jsfiddle and share the link ?

Comment: [You might want to look at this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api)

Comment: For debugging purpose you should use console.log() instead of alerts. This a best practice, plus this is nicer since you can log any object.

Comment: Another best practice would be not to use <br/> to add some spaces in your document but to use CSS instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3Gxf/ Heres is the jsfiddle link. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey here is a working fiddle with your code, and some examples of ways to debug your js :

http://jsfiddle.net/QxP7p/3/

As you see you can do nice stuff like :

```
console.log("distance : ");
console.log(distance);
```

Hope it helps

They were a few mistakes as well, couldn't help fixing them

Comment: is it working ? please tell me the mistakes. I am new to js and cant figure it out

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? You should see the distances correctly logged in your console. (I personnally tried it with two friends, one in Paris and one in Berlin)

Comment: its saying "rows" undefined . Line 66

Comment: And what response is logged?

Comment: TypeError: rows is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)

Comment: There actually was a mistake, I was initializing the distance[i] array in the wrong place, here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QxP7p/2/

Comment: What's your browser? I don't get this error. This cannot be undefined, since the line just above is var rows = response.rows;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23415/discussion-between-user1263375-and-champi)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug is to use firebug and `console.log()` variables or messages at certain points in your script, so that you can better understand what is going on at various steps of your script.  You can see the output in the Console tab of firebug.

You can also add breakpoints and watches from some of the other tabs. For example in the DOM tab you can rightclick on a variable and add a watch, or from the Script tab you can click on a position in your script to set a breakpoint or watch, and it will stop the script at that point and/or show a dump of vars at that point.