# jQuery ajax doesn't work in IE8

Tags: ajax, jquery

Here's a very simple jQuery example :

http://www.ihaols.com/geo.html

Code :

```
    $(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
                var address = encodeURIComponent($('#k').val());
                $.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ address + '&sensor=false', function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        var l = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                        var v = l.lat + ',' + l.lng;
                        $('#r').val(v);
                });
        });
});
```

But this code doesn't work in IE7/8, I've already include `json2.js` in it.

Comment: IE 7 and 8 [don't support CORS](http://caniuse.com/cors) and this doesn't appear to be using JSONP.

Comment: @MrROY - your code is not running in any browser. In FireFox 23.0.1 on Mac, I am getting TypeError: data.results[0] is undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2921745 may be worthwhile. Though, if you're heavily [concerned with rate limiting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2921745#comment6419581_2921970), then you'll probably have to use a server-side proxy on your own origin.

Comment: @MrRoy Me too faced almost similar situation ,In my case cross-domain AJAX call was the root cause. So I created one php page in my project for parse google api json with pure server side code (not used ajax). 
then that php page is called with ajax.