# Website is returning "CSI/tbsd_" and "CSI/_tbnd" errors in browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I have a website that is returning some odd warning messages and errors in both Firefox and Chrome.

Firefox returns these errors:

```
GET http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round 200 OK 7c8e43d.js (line 18)
13:27:41.46 CSI/tbsd_
13:27:41.48 CSI/_tbnd
```

Chrome returns this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm guessing that this problem is related to Google Fonts API and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` How can I fix the errors for this?

Comment: @bybe - I've added a screeshot. I can't do much more to add details, as I'm not able to know where it's coming from.

Comment: Also your website has other problems other than that of the Google font, event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. (outdated JS or Jquery. Another problem in your HTML code on line 71 for example `<img src="#" alt="logo" width=300>` should be `<img src="yourimage.jpg" alt="logo" width="300">` missing `""` on the width and src must always have a value otherwise your going to have MIME problems. Anyway, checkout Stack Overflow for problems relating to CODE in future instances.

Comment: @bybe - Thank you for edit and your help. Now I know it comes from the fonts.

Comment: @bybe - How could I migrate this question to stackoverflow?

Comment: Its quite irritating that Google is writing to my console.log. How can I stop this? What happens if they decide to print a 500 page novel to my console? Bad practice...

Comment: Why would they ever do that? They're just 2 messages, it won't hurt. If you really don't like it, then `console.log=()=>{}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The log entries for `CSI/tbsd_` and `CSI/_tbnd` are not errors but time stamps, which are generated by the Google APIs.

Time stamps can be generated in JavaScript using the [`console.timeStamp()` function](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.timeStamp).

You can also see these time stamp logs on google.com:

[image]

Within Firebug they are even displayed as olive lines within the [*Net* panel timeline](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Timeline):

[image]

So these log messages are nothing to worry about. They just provide some information for debugging purposes.

Your actual problem related to the error you get in Chrome is caused by a cross-domain request. So the browser is blocking it for security reasons related to the same origin policy. There's a [tutorial on "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (CORS)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) at html5rocks.com.

See also related questions on stackoverflow:

- [XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059658/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)
- ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w)

Comment: I don't want to see this in my console. Can I stop Google from doing this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to stop Google from sending those messages, though at least in the Chrome DevTools you should be able to filter those messages out by typing `-CSI/tbsd_ -CSI/_tbnd` into the filter field.

Answer (score 2):

I've also spotted this on my site recently, particularly since adding Google DFP (Doubleclick) code to my page.

I found the following description on this site [SpanishDict Engineering](http://engineering.spanishdict.com/blog/2014/1/9/inspecting-the-inspector)

> csi?tbsd is a console.time call comng from google

That seems to make sense in the context of my web page. I hope it makes similar sense for you?