# GetServerDate with JSON protocol in JQuery, not budging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

So i'm trying to make a simple ajax call to retrieve some data from a file on a server. I can access the file through the web browser, and i've followed tutorials on this subject to the T, but it has gotten me nowhere. 
Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://www.mychoicetechnologies.com/Services/FMSUtilities.asmx/GetServerDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg) 
  {        
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Success! Retrieved a server response using AJAX.";
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error)
  {        
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML =  "1." + error +   "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "2." + xhr +     "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "3." + status +  "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "The script has failed";
  }
});
</script>
```

When I run this script the output is:

> 1.
>
> 2.[object Object]
>
> 3.error
>
> The script has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this in Chrome, the console says:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.mychoicetechnologies.com/Services/FMSUtilities.asmx/GetServerDate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1

This means the service you are trying to hit does not allow requests from other domains.

See [XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20059658/701303)

*Edited to add:*

It would make more sense to do a `GET` instead of a `POST`, since you are only trying to read, not write.  And the service is returning XML, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now looking into using Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the server-side to allow my script through. If I elminate dataType: "json" this becomes CORS protocol, correct?

Comment: I've not used CORS much, but my impression is that it's only dependent on the Origin/Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers.  `dataType` simply affects how JQuery handles the response once it comes back.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I've got this sorted out properly. My next issue is one of retrieving the page's content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227139/xml-retrieval-with-ajax-returning-document-object-how-do-i-get-the-content