# XML retrieval with AJAX returning [Document Object], How do I get the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I asked a question similar to this yesterday, but have since made progress on the problem.
Now, all that stands in my way is figuring out how to turn this success response into something tangible. Right now I'm getting a return of "[Document Object]" at best. In attempting to retrieve the responseText of the field I was getting "undefined".

This appears to be a core misunderstanding of this protocol on my part, so if anyone can solve this problem and provide me with a tutorial resource to move forward with i'd very much appreciate it.

```
var returnval;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://www.mychoicetechnologies.com/Services/FMSUtilities.asmx/GetServerDate",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {

        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Success! Retrieved a server response using AJAX.<br>";
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "1." + error + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "2." + xhr + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "3." + status + "<br>";
        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "The script has failed.";
    }
});
```

Regards,

-Sean

EDIT:
I've discovered the solution I was looking for.

```
msg.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I had to jump through the xml nodes to get to the value of the field I was looking for.
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_get.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use console.log then alert, like that :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://www.mychoicetechnologies.com/Services/FMSUtilities.asmx/GetServerDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8", 
  success: function (msg) 
  {     

     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = "Success! Retrieved a server response using AJAX.<br>";
     console.log(msg);
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error)
  {        
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML =  "1." + error +   "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "2." + xhr +     "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML += "3." + status +  "<br>";
     document.getElementById('area').innerHTML +=           "The script has failed.";
  }
});
```

If you use Google Chrome, use the shortcut "ctrl + shift + j", and retry you query.

Comment: Brilliant. So I HAVE in fact retrieved the page content, now I just need to decide how to process it.

Comment: When you "debug" your query, I notice you to use, in the error part :
console.error(arguments); // It will show you all the argument get by the function

Comment: If I wanted to retrieve the contents... the proper direction from here would be to parse the xml?