# Ajax success returns empty value

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            type: "GET",
            url:"http://simplewebsite.com",
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data);
            }
        });
```

I simply access a site, but success returns empty data. where as it works fine using curl. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Google restricts accessing their page using AJAX from a different domain. curl does not make an AJAX request, so it works.

Comment: Thanks alot. Please can you check my edited question. Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: If you do not have access to the server configuration, than you'd better to use some server proxy on your side to avoid cross-domain issue.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of cross-domain ajax calls.

You can't just do an Ajax call to any website and expect it to work. The server needs to be setup properly for that.

Use ajax calls to contact webservices which allow cross-domain calls, OR to contact your own server. Any other request will likely fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sounds like you have a crossdomain problem because there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response.
```

If this is not the case a browser usually does not allow to request a service located on another domain than the javascript that is triggering the request.

Google does not allow cross domain in

Please check here for for further details

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059658/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

And check console here

http://jsbin.com/jajimira/1