# how to read current domain url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Say i have a current url showing  `http://localhost.com/welcome/blah_blah` ,from this url i am expecting to get only `http://localhost.com/`     into a page.

How to do this??

I know `echo current_url();` gives full  url. But i want only the `http://localhost.com` excluding controller_name,clasname etc.

**Expected output**

if my base_url=`http://www.exaple.com/folder` & current_url=`http://exaple.com/folder/class/method/blah_blah` ,then i want domain name as `exaple.com` NOT the `www.exaple.com`  !

I am [facing a issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059658/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you get it by this function

```
function siteURL() {
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    return $protocol . $domainName;
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work but he is using CodeIgniter which already has this function built into one of its helpers.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this  later on. It will be great if i can get this using codeigniter

Comment: He ask for a codeigniter solution not how to create a php function that solve the problem.

Comment: @MirkoBrombin You are right and I have mentioned in the answer that It is PHP function. Please check other answers for CI solutions

Comment: You can edit the anwser or add new anwser to help others. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `base_url()` from the URL helper. It returns the website domain without the index.php as configured in your `config.php`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

**Updated after additional information:**

With the extra information you posted if you simply want the domain name ONLY and no subdomains (www.) then this will work fine:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$url_parts = parse_url(current_url());
echo str_replace('www.', '', $url_parts['host']);
```

However if you still needed http or https then this would do the job:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$url_parts = parse_url(current_url());
echo $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . str_replace('www.', '', $url_parts['host']);
```

This however would only remove www. subdomains, but could easily be adapted if there were potentially any others.

Comment: Of course you must load the URL helper first `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Sorry! Not helpful. suppose if i have set $base_url="www.example.com/project"  then this logic will not work.  I asked the current url....

Comment: Actually you did not mention this in your initial questions before the edit. I've updated my answer with a another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following function to the url_helper.php,Then call   `getDomain()` like you are calling `base_url()`

```
  function getDomain()
  {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return preg_replace("/^[\w]{2,6}:\/\/([\w\d\.\-]+).*$/","$1", $CI->config->slash_item('base_url'));
  }
```

Comment: i tried to show using `echo $this->getDomain();` but it shows error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method calculate::getDomain() in D:\xampp\htdocs\ecc\application\controllers\calculate.php on line 33`  ??

Comment: simply call getDomain() like base_url(),Because you have added that function in a helper

Comment: i tested your code but its not what i want. You have basically customizes the `base_url()` , similarly i want to customize the `current_url()`.  How to do this?                                     For Example: if my base_url=`http://www.exaple.com/folder` & current_url=`http://exaple.com/folder/class/method/blah_blah` ,then i want domain name as `exaple.com` NOT the `www.exaple.com`  !

Comment: @badtimings Oh,sorry.I think it will help you.we can find any other methods soon

Comment: oh it's working. use *$this->getDomain();* if using in class otherwise call it directly

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the following code and you will get you current domain name. either its http or https

```
 $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $url =  $protocol . $domainName;
```