# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am trying to call a page using javascript but insted of getting response i get the following error

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://account.domain.com/testimonial/user_message",
    success:function(res){

        alert(res);

    }

});
```

when i call this code i am getting an error in console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://account.domin.com/admin/testimonial/user_message. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

if i put this url into the browser then it show me the result but if i call this using jquery then why i am getting this error and how can i call this url

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource?lq=1) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059658/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers block cross domain XMLHttpRequest. Please follow [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for more information about how to do XMLHttpRequest to different domains.

Answer (score 2):

use this code instead

```
url: <?php echo site_url('testimonial/user_message');?>
//it will automatically get your base url and append your parameter in site_url.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: he's asking why the XMLHttpRequest cannot be loaded so i suggested this code, cause in code igniter, it's hard to use url since it has alot of folder.

Comment: If you're answering a question, please be more specific and explain your answer, so that it will be helpful to others also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code might help you solve your troubles.

```
url: <?= site_url('testimonial/user_message');?>
```