# How to avoid IE to download the json response

Tags: javascript, html, json, internet-explorer

We are using google API for address validation, below is the sample HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function test(){

$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAf8jLP-ytDdra3sQD5M53l9Eh4zzgn_B4',
{
sensor: false,
address: "1907+SW+28TH+ST+BENTONVILLE+72712"
},
function( data, textStatus ) {
alert(data.results[0].formatted_address);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="test()">Click to fade in boxes</button><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine in chrome and firefox. I'm getting the alert.  But in IE this code is not responding. I observe that IE is trying to download the response. Is there a way to stop the download and get as a stream(as like in chrome)?

Comment: I remember once I had the same issue, take a look to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921745/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-to-google-maps-api

Comment: In this I'm not even getting the response